# How to configure SSHD on CoreOS after installation?

Tags: ssh, configuration, systemd, coreos

I've got the CoreOS running and I would like to remove the ability to login using passwords to the sshd.
I went through the docs of the CoreOS in [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-sshd.html), but I am quite new to the systemd. I went through the man page, but I am a bit lost on it.
I know I have to create a dropin file inside `/etc/system.d/system/`, but I have no idea, in which section of the file, should I put the `PasswordAuthentication no` option. Since I work remotely, I don't want to screw up and not be able to login again...

I would be grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a chat on #coreos on freenode, I have learned the simples thing of all.

`/etc` is not read only, but `sshd_config` is a symlink to a file on `/usr` which is. I just had to remove the symlink and create the file by hand... eh.

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you will find `PasswordAuthentication` there. Then restart the SSHD with `systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: Thanks @Stone but this is CoreOS and the file is on a read only partition, that's why I have to do this using a dropin file.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was misread CoreOS to CentOS... :(

Comment: The configuration of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is in the very first configuration block of your linked instructions. Just add the line.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm sorry I don't understand. Sorry for my ignorance, but  where do I add the line?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider if your advice was to modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then as stated before, this file is on a read only partition, and according to the docs, the only way to configure sshd after first boot is by using the dropin files: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-sshd.html What I miss is info on a section which I could use to pass the `PasswordAuthentication` option

Comment: @Krystian I have absolutely no experience with CoreOS, so I can't give you any specifics. But the very first part of the documentation you linked is about modifying the sshd_config file. It also says that you have to do this before the first boot. The only thing I can tell you fore sure is that systemd is not involved in setting the `PasswordAuthentication` option.